# Mapstruct generated classes are not found if the application is run from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotation-processing, mapstruct

I have a Java 11 based application built with Gradle 4.8.1 which uses Mapstruct 1.3.0.Final. I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.2.3 for development.

**Problem:**

The application does't work if I start it from IntelliJ IDEA, however it works when it is built with Gradle.

I get the following error in run time when I start the app from IntelliJ:

```
ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for com.mycompany.MyMapper
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:75)
    at org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers.getMapper(Mappers.java:58)
```

**My project setup:**

I use one more annotation processing tool - Lombok which works fine. All together I have them in my dependencies like this:

```
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10')
annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10')
compile('org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final')
annotationProcessor('org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final')
```

**How to reproduce:** It is enough to start a unit test from IntelliJ UI that requires a class generated with Mapstruct.

**Question:** How to make IntelliJ IDEA correctly apply Mapstruct annotation processors?

**What I have tried:** I went through similar issues on StackOveflow and [on GitHub](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/issues/45). Unfortunately, they didn't help. They are either using old versions of the lib, an old JVM or simply the solutions don't work.

Comment: Do you have "Build and Run using Gradle" set in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set "Build and Run using Gradle" in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle"

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Why this isn't the default IDE setting when working with Gradle projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue even after using @y.bedrov answer.
Below changes worked for me:
Add generated directory as source code.

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += "build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"
}
```

Add componentModel for Mapper class- (This tells Micronaut to create a bean for the mapper.)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")
```